# Full Calendar - refetchResources when next or prev button clicked with parameters

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am confused on how to refresh the resources list (json ).
I am using this code inside the calendar initialization

```
resources: {
                url: 'classroomlist.php',
                method: 'GET',
                extraParams: { dte: dte,roomtype:roomtype }                 
              },
```

the file classroomlist.php will bring the list of available classrooms according to the parameters dte which is the center date of the calendar and the type of the classroom
I want to refresh the list of the ressources when the user clicks on the next or prev buttons of the calendar, I am using fullcalendar v6.
Any suggestions???

I have tried calendar.refetchResources(); but it's not allowing to add parameters

Comment: You can specify resources as a function, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function - if that function could "fetch" the necessary dte and roomtype values from the outside itself, then I suppose if should work with refetchResources as well then.